# Geometry Nodes Flower Grow - Can't get rotational control of the leaves and petals

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've watched a bunch of Geo flower tutorials and read a lot of articles, but I haven't been able to figure out how to better place and control leaves or petals at the tops of the flower stems.

I'm betting that this is a simple case of me not knowing what fields to use.

I start with a base geometry:

[image]

Then I create seeds / distribute points on faces:

[image]

Then create the stems:

[image]

Now Adding flowers is where everything collapses:
This image is one attempt. The leaves rotate correctly and they are at the top of each stem, but as you can see, they are all identical and I can't figure out how to randomize them. If I randomize this it makes them all exactly the same random amounts.To be clear, I want to randomize the X and Y of the flower petals so they aren't all exactly rotated and look the same.
(I'm using the output of the Stem's `Trim Curve` node to a `Resample Curve` node, to bring the points over) (perhaps that is a mistake?)

[image]

So I tried a different way. The leaves here are rotated correctly, but they run down the length of the stem instead of around the top point of the stem. If I try an Endpoint I get only one leaf at the top.

[image]

I know it's some simple math or something but for the life of me I can't get it right. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you are looking for a setup of this kind:

[image]
<sub>(Simplified setup)</sub>

If I understand correctly, you've actually solved most of the task already, it's just that you haven't managed to rotate the petals for the individual flowers yet.

The trick here is, after instantiating the circles where you create the petals, to capture their index.

You do this with `Capture Attribute` in the domain *Instance*. This way you have a unique index per instance, and can use this value additionally to calculate the rotation of the petals.

In this example I simply used the node `Random Value` for this and used the previously captured index as *ID*.

I then add this randomly generated value here with the rotation of the petals along a circle.

With `Vector Rotate` and `Align Euler to Vector` I then create the corresponding *Rotation* for the individual instances.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

---

**Update**

You can, of course, add more random angles by adding different angles to the rotation. Note that these values are in radians, not degrees.

Because of this setup, each individual point at which a petal is created has a unique index and does not represent instances, so too is the rotation created for each petal unique.

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thanks so much for your reply.  but I think I didn't specify the randomness I was looking for.. I don't need to rotate on the Z axis randomly.. because you can't tell the difference.. the flowers still look exactly the same.. what I'm looking for is a randomness to the X and Y so all the flowers have randomness. I tried to figure that out, but I don't really understand your Geo flow.. Do I need an entirely different set up to do such a thing?? @quellenform

Comment: @GorkEnterprises You would actually only have to extend this setup a little. I have changed the answer accordingly. You would just have to add additional values for the angles, and each petal would get a unique rotation. And yes, you would actually have to build the setup differently, since instances are not changeable afterwards (apart from the transformation of the mesh). Instance == Duplicate of an object.

Comment: Again, thank you for the update.. However, again, I don't think this is working.. it seems to be exactly the same random on every flower, but just a random Z rotation, which makes it seem like every flower petal is rotated randomly, but on closer inspection the flowers have identical randomness in the X and Y, but still only Z is actually random. it's even apparent in the image you uploaded.. the flowers are identical in the X and Y, but just randomly rotated on Z. You did mention that the setup would have to be build differently..? I've been trying to modify your set up, but to no avail.

Comment: @GorkEnterprises Download my example file and add another node `Random Value` as seen in my update. If you do it this way, you will notice that each petal gets a unique rotation on each axis. You can check it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaVZZ.jpg

Comment: I think I was using the random node as Float instead of Vector. I think it's working now. Thanks for the assistance. Now to the task of animating it all.. oh boy.. we may speak again.. :-)